# Introducing freeze column in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am looking in for a python code that allows me to freeze first two columns in my webpage when i scroll sideways.

Comment: How could this be a "Python code"? This has to do with front-end display.

Comment: Yes, this is html/css/js task. Not Django/Python.

Comment: I am new to Django. Can you provide me with few link to work on front end part of django web development...like writing custom widget and including that to the code and also using js in templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not Django. This is a javascript/css/html question.

First of all you have to become clearer on what do you mean by saying "column". People often use similar words to describe different things. Try to be as clear as possible. Give an example. Paste some code. Did you try yourself, first, before asking for help? Did you bing/google your problem? What did you find.

The more details you provide, the better answers you get. It is as simple as that.

Having said that, Django is mainly a backend framework. Django helps you model your data before displaying them to the user. I doubt you will find a django widget[3] for what you ask.

Finally if you really need to start with Django, the best place is its awesome documentation[1]. Then you can get a book. I suggest this[2]. Although it is a bit of an old texture, it gives you a step by step procedure as simple as it gets in order to build you first site in django. It even covers some jQuery which I am sure you will need.

hope that helps.

[1] https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/

[2] [http://www.amazon.com/Django-Website-Development-Ayman-Hourieh/dp/1847196780/ref=sr_1_4?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1334921864&sr=1-4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847196780)

[3] http://djangosnippets.org/